# Tried to print one result that duplicate

Tags: python

I tried to print out one result that duplicate.

Codes:

```
words = 'ups downs downs love love like go go go'
words = words.split(' ')
TotalWords = len(words)
print 'TotalWords =', TotalWords
for w in words:
    if words.count(w) > 1:
        print w, words.count(w)
    else:
        print w, words.count(w)
```

Results:

```
TotalWords = 9
ups 1
downs 2
downs 2
love 2
love 2
like 1
go 3
go 3
go 3
```

I want to get:

```
TotalWords = 9
ups 1
downs 2
love 2
like 1
go 3
```

Anything that I missed? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you `print w, words.count(w)` for each occurence of `w` in `words`. Use `set` to get rid of duplicates.

```
words = 'ups downs downs love love like go go go'
words = words.split(' ')
TotalWords = len(words)
print 'TotalWords =', TotalWords
for w in set(words):
    print w, words.count(w)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're counting, don't forget about Counter!

```
from collections import Counter
words = 'ups downs downs love love like go go go'
print 'TotalWords =', len(words.split(' '))
words = Counter(words.split(' '))
for word, count in words.items():
    print word, count
```